# How to run script multiple times from command line?

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to run `~bin/ap` script multiple times with

```
dims@pterosaur:~$ while true; ~bin/ap; sleep 2; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

where

```
dims@pterosaur:~$ cat bin/ap
#!/bin/sh
MAC="$(iwconfig wlp2s0 | sed -n 's/.*Access Point: //p' | xargs)"

if [ "$MAC" = "60:E3:27:8D:AC:F0" ]; then
    MAC="tplink2"
elif [ "$MAC" = "60:E3:27:8D:7A:A6" ]; then
    MAC="tplink1"
fi

echo "[$MAC]"
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: missed `do` after the first `;`

Comment: Should be `while true; do "$HOME/bin/ap" …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (also from @IporSircer comment) this instead:

`while true;`**do**`~/bin/ap; sleep 2; done`